# Sitecore 8.0 not publishing not updating CD server

Tags: publishing

This is a problem we seem to have at random. It'll go away for a while and typically rears its ugly head whenever we have a deployment.

The problem:

We logon to the CM server, update a page and publish it to CM and the
CM shows the updated content then 
We publish to CD and the
CD does not update after publishing.

We've checked the web-live database and the changes do make it there ok.

If we update the `web.config` or restart iis etc then the website does display the new updated content which leads me to believe it's some kind of caching issue.

we have this in our `web.config` files (it was playing around with this that we released saving any change made the website refresh)

```
 <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
    <handler type="OurSite.Common.Sc.Handlers.CacheHandler, OurSite.Common" method="OnPublishEnd"></handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
    <handler type="OurSite.Common.Sc.Handlers.CacheHandler, OurSite.Common" method="OnPublishEnd"></handler>
  </event>
```

any help at this point would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see any errors in log file on cm/cd servers? Have you been able to find the event on the publishqueue table?

Comment: EventQueue table, not publishqueue. Are you sharing a core database across CM/CD? Is your website actually called `website`?

Comment: Were you able to see any error message on the sitecore-client after publishing?

Comment: Can you please see above publish:end:remote setting is same when you view it using /sitecore/showconfig.aspx . Just thinking if above setting on web.config has been overridden by a patch file or not..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on an 8.0 install a while ago where the culprit was insufficient write permissions in the data folder.  If that is the case you should see some issues in the log.  This case was compounded by incorrect config files on the different server types so I'd check those too.